# Restricting C# DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, datepicker

I need to give my users a way of selecting any valid Saturday in a WPF app. Right now, I just use the DatePicker and error if the day of the week isn't Saturday.

```
DateTime selectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.ToString());
if (selectedDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please pick a Saturday");
}
```

I'd rather do it in the control and simply slide back to the next Saturday or make Sun-Fri unclickable. This should be easy, but I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at the [`BlackoutDates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property.  You can subscribe to the [`DisplayDateChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydatechanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) Event to catch when the user switches months and reinitialize the list of `BlackoutDates` for that new month.

Comment: I'm not sure I can catch the event when the user goes forward or backward a month. Without that, wouldn't you have to blackout all possible dates during the initialization?

Comment: Use the [`DisplayDateChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydatechanged(v=VS.95).aspx) Event on the underlying Calendar object.

Comment: DisplayDateChanged is for the Calendar control, but it doesn't appear that I can get a handle (or event) for the pop-up Calendar that DatePicker creates. DisplaDateChanged definitely doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see any other solutions.  I don't know how Calendar/DatePicker works, but from code samples I've seen they have separate id's so it seems like you should be able to get a handle to both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how clear you need to be to the user, you could use subtle color highlighting of the control (forecolor, backcolor) to indicate an error. Then use the message box for if they try to ignore the warning.